# Get indexed item from genericlist throws error

Tags: c#, list, collections, generics

I'm trying to get a certain indexed item by number from a generic list and I'm getting: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[typename]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'. errors.

What I'm trying to achieve is to loop (forward or backwards) to a certain list based upon a inherited baseclass; like so (or something similar anyway):

```
public class Fruit
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
public class Apple : Fruit
{
  public bool IsSour {get;set;}
}
public class Orange : Fruit
{
  public bool Juicy {get;set;}
}
public List<Apple> Apples = new List<Apple>();
public List<Orange> Oranges = new List<Oranges>();
```

what I'd like to to is something like this:

```
public string[] BuildList(object GenericListHere, bool Backwards)
{
  for(int i=GenericListHere.Length-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
    string MyName = GenericListHere[i].Name;
```

The above is somewhat pseudocoded, but I'd like to throw in either the apples or oranges list to get result. 
I don't know beforehand which object I'm getting, so I get the Count/Length like this (not psuedocoded) where TestObj is just the object I'm getting:

```
int iBound = -1;
try
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo oInfo = TestObj.GetType().GetProperty("Count");
    iBound = (int)oInfo.GetValue(TestObj, null);
}
catch
{
```

And if the iBound >= 0 it's a collection. The next part.. I'm somewhat lost...

```
 if (iBound != -1)
 {
      int iLoopStart = (backwardsLoop ? iBound - 1 : 0);
      int iLoopEnd = (backwardsLoop ? -1 : iBound);
      int iLoopDifference = (backwardsLoop ? -1 : +1);
      for (int iLoop = iLoopStart; iLoop != iLoopEnd; iLoop += iLoopDifference)
      {
           // THIS IS REALLY BAD CODED.. BUT I DONT GET IT
           object VarCollection = TestObj;
           object[] arInt = new object[1];
           arInt.SetValue(iLoop, 0);
           Type[] tArray = new Type[1];
           tArray.SetValue(typeof(int), 0);
           object oElem = ((System.Collections.Generic.List<object>)VarCollection)[iLoop];
```

What I'd really like is something like : VarCollection[iLoop], but that doesn't seem to work..

Anyone experienced with these kind of lists? TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast it to `IList` and use the indexer.

Comment: @riffnl: No, you don't. Or please explain why you would think or assume that.

Comment: "Because the compiler said so" would've propably been my answer.. but using System.Collections does seem to do this trick.

Comment: @riffnl: Hehe, like I commented to Marc, people forget about the non generic base implementations.

Answer (score 1):

I really think reflection isn't the answer here; generics should be more than enough for your needs. It also appears that you don't *actually* need to access elements from the list by index since the intention appears to simply be to project a sequence of fruits to a sequence of fruit-names. If you *do* need to access elements by index however (e.g. if you stick with your `for` loop), it shouldn't be an issue if you use generics; the indexer on `IList<T>` as well as its `Count`property is easily discoverable in generic code.

The following solution, which uses a generic constraint, should work fine in .NET 3.5:

```
public static string[] BuildList<T>(IList<T> list, bool backwards) 
    where T : Fruit
{
  var names = list.Select(fruit => fruit.Name);
  return (backwards ? names.Reverse() : names).ToArray();
}
```

In .NET 4.0, a `List<Apple>` is correctly recognized as an`IEnumerable<Fruit>`. Consequently, the following signature should work too:

```
public static string[] BuildList(IEnumerable<Fruit> list, bool backwards)
```

On another note, you might want to consider returning an `IEnumerable<string>`instead, and let the caller push the results into an array if it so desires.

Comment: The names are a somewhat simplified example. I need to do more with the objects itself, but I don't really know what list I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you are having to work with `object` and reflection, you should probably simply use the non-generic `IList` / `ICollection` interfaces rather than the generic `IList<T>` / `ICollection<T>` / `List<T>`; you will still have indexer, iterate, add, etc

Comment: Alas, I don't have anything to say about that. I didn't build the base of the objects I'm getting to work with; I'm just getting the objects as they're being passed.

Comment: @riffnl - but they still *are* `IList` etc, regardless of what they describe themselves as. Just cast...